# How to save Review 's Track Changes setting for a .docx file in Ms Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

When using the `Track Changes` feature in Microsoft Word, I usually have to turn of the formation checkbox to omit the displayed formation changed (it looks meaningless to me compared with the updated text)

Everytime we reopen this tracked .docx file, the formation is displayed again. I need Word to remember that I turn that off. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is at least a partial solution that worked for me in Word 2010.

First, do a one-time settings change:

- Go to **File** -> **Options** -> **Trust Center**
- Click on **Trust Center Settings...**
- Click on **Privacy Options** in the left pane
- Uncheck the **Make hidden markup visible when opening or saving** checkbox

Then, you have do to this for each file in which you want to suppress Formatting markup balloons:

- **Review** -> **Track Changes** dropdown -> **Change Tracking Options...**
- Uncheck the **Track Formatting** checkbox, hit **OK**
- **Review** -> **Show Markup** dropdown -> Uncheck **Formatting**
- Save the file

Thereafter, it should no longer display Formatting markup balloons for that file.